# Save mp4 video opencv

Tags: c, opencv

I have mp4 video, and after drawing i need to save it.
I am trying to use

```
VideoWriter video("outcpp.avi", CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, Size(1280, 720));
```

But after saving this file is broken.
full code(i am using opencv 2.4.13):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
Mat src;
void mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int, void*)
{
    if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        rectangle(src, Point(x, y), Point(x+10, y+10), Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        imshow("src", src);
    }
}

int main(void)
{       
    CvCapture* cap = cvCreateFileCapture("1.mp4");
    VideoWriter video("outcpp.avi", CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, Size(1280, 720));
    while (1)
    {
        src = cvQueryFrame(cap);
        namedWindow("src", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("src", src);
        setMouseCallback("src", mouse_callback);
        video.write(src);
        waitKey(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say it is broken what does it mean ? How do you try to read it ? moreover, you don't need to call `setMouseCallback` on each frame, just create the "src" window with `namedWindow("src")` and set the mouse callback before entering the loop. One more remark : why are you recording the same frame as you're reading ? if you want to record the rectangle you draw, be sure this is not the case.

Comment: This code gives me error in ```src  = cvQueryFrame(cap)``` , whu you are not using ```videocapture()``` ? This api not c++ ? Please edit your question

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk i fotgot to say that it opencv 2.4.13

Comment: @antoine i am trying to open saved file, but it show me error, that file is damaged. You mean that i cant save video with rectangles using this?

Comment: This is not about the version. Your c++ tag is wrong you should edit question

Comment: @Maksim to save the image with rectangle you should write after waiting for user input. But again : how do you open the file ? did you try several player ? I guess your player can't read MPJG in MP4 container. You could try to open the saved video with your program directly to see if the file is OK or not.

Comment: @antoine oh, its realy stupid mistake:). Opencv cant read this file also, as i understand it happened because i try to use different interfaces.

Comment: could you post the `outcpp.mp4` file womewhere ? how big is it ?

Comment: you'll have to close the VideoWriter correctly in the end. To save  .mp4 you should use `VideoWriter video("outcpp.mp4", -1, 10, Size(1280, 720));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seams everything is working with `VideoCapture`. Why do you use C interface for reading and C++ for write?

I only move `video.write` after wait key to capture user clicks in video.

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    vector<Rect> trafficLights;

    VideoCapture cap("/Users/alex/Documents/my_projects/hahaton_cams/kfu2.mp4");
    VideoWriter video("outcpp.avi", CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10, Size(1280, 720));
    while (cap.read(src)) {
        namedWindow("src", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("src", src);
        setMouseCallback("src", mouse_callback);

        if (waitKey(0) == 'q')
            break;
        video.write(src); // to capture user clicks
    }

    return 0;
}
```

OpenCV 4.2

Comment: Maybe you should add the reason of adding waitKey() before videowrite? Its cos of videowriter taking the previous frame before drawing.

Comment: > I only move `video.write` after wait key to capture user clicks in video.

Without it this code just write video without user clicks.

Comment: Okey your code is right. I just wanted you to add the reason as edit. The mistake is that but the reason: videowriter will take pure frame to write instead of proccessed frame in the question side.